# Compactness of support of a function in Rudin's proof of the Urysohn Lemma

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I was self-studying *Complex and Real Analysis* by Rudin. In the proof of Urysohn's lemma (Theorem 2.12) I can't understand why the support of $f$ is compact. Why is it? [The proof is here](http://i1250.photobucket.com/albums/hh527/checkhokan22/Mobile%20Uploads/Screenshot_2017-06-06-18-34-53_zps9ciaz93c.png)

Comment: You can, however, edit the question to include the statement of the result and its proof - see the [MathJax tutorial](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's recall Rudin's definitions and preliminary work. Let $K$ be a compact set, $V$ be an open set and  $\lbrace V_r\rbrace_{r\in\lbrack0,1\rbrack}$ be a collection of open sets such that:

- $\forall r\in\lbrack0,1\rbrack$, $\overline{V_r}$ is compact;
- $s>r$ implies $\overline{V_s}\subset V_r$;
- $K\subset V_1\subset \overline{V_1}\subset\dots\subset V_0\subset \overline{V_0}\subset V$.

Define $f_r(x)=r\cdot \chi_{V_r}$, were $\chi_A$ is the characteristic function and $f(x)=\sup_r f_r(x)$.

---

For a real valued function $f:U\to \mathbb{R}$, we have 
$$\mathrm{supp}(f)=\lbrace x\in U\;;\; f(x)\neq 0\rbrace.$$
Here, suppose we have $f(x)\neq 0$. Then, this means that $\sup_r f_r(x)>0$. Furthermore, there exists an $r\in\lbrack 0,1\rbrack$ with $f_r(x)>0$. By definition of $f_r$, this means that $x\in V_r$ and consequently in $V_0$ because of the chain of inclusion noted above. It follows that 
$$\mathrm{supp}(f)\subset V_0\subset \overline{V_0}$$
which is what we wanted to show.